# RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 100 but got size 1 for tensor number 1 in the list

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I'm new to PyTorch not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong, below is the code

```
x_np, y_np = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100,n_features=1,noise=20,random_state=0)

x = torch.from_numpy(x_np.astype(np.float32))
y = torch.from_numpy(y_np.astype(np.float32))

y = y.view(y.shape[0],1)
n_samples, n_features = x.shape

class Regression(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, inputsize, outputsize, hiddensize):
    super(Regression, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hiddensize
    self.input_size = inputsize
    self.output_size = outputsize
    self.i2h = nn.Linear(self.input_size+self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
    self.h2o = nn.Linear(self.input_size+self.hidden_size, self.output_size)
  def forward(self, x):
    hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
    print(x.shape)
    print(hidden.shape)
    combined = torch.cat((x,hidden), 1)
    hidden = self.i2h(combined)
    output = self.h2o(combined)
    return output

model = Regression(n_features, n_features, 16)

lr = 0.01
loss = nn.MSELoss()
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = lr)

for epoch in range(1000):
  ypred = model(x)
  l = loss(y, ypred)
  l.backward()
  opt.step()
  opt.zero_grad()
  if epoch % 100 == 0:
    [w, b] = model.parameters()
    print(f'epoch {epoch+1}: w = {w[0][0].item():.3f}, loss = {l:.8f}')
```

While training, I am getting this error

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 100 but got size 1 for tensor number 1 in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

i2h maps `self.input_size + self.hidden_size` dimension to `self.hidden_size`, so for h2o, you have to define a mapping starting from `self.hidden` dimension. Also, you have to update the forward accordingly. Here is the complete code:

```
class Regression(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, inputsize, outputsize, hiddensize):
    super(Regression, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hiddensize
    self.input_size = inputsize
    self.output_size = outputsize
    self.i2h = nn.Linear(self.input_size+self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
    self.h2o = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)
  def forward(self, x):
    hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
    print(x.shape)
    print(hidden.shape)
    combined = torch.cat((x,hidden), 1)
    hidden = self.i2h(combined)
    output = self.h2o(hidden)
    return output
```